# python replace fileinput with seek

Tags: python, file

I have got a file which terminates with `</END>` there are chances the file may contains blank lines after `</END>`. I do not care about blank lines. But the last non blank word is `</END>`. I need to append a couple of lines before the `</END>`. I have done this with `fileinput`

```
for each_line in fileinput.input("testme",inplace=True):
    if each_line.strip() == '</END>':
        print "\nAdding ^.*"+source_resource+".*$ \\"
        print destination+" [R="+http_code+",L]"
    print each_line,
```

Can some experts please advise how can this be achieved with `seek`. I believe `seek` is very handy for cursor positing.

Comment: Is it not working the way you have written it?

Comment: @Burhan Khalid No I have received my desired result with `fileinput`. I would like to know how the same can be achieved with `seek`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 possible approaches, one using an in-place write and the other implies creating a copy of the file.

The second approach is very easy to implement:

```
with open(src_path, "r") as in_f, open(dest_path, "w") as out_f:
    for line in in_f:
        if line == "</END>":
            out_f.write("whatever you want")
        out_f.write(line)
        out_f.write('\n')
```

For the first approach, we need to detect the end line and move back to its beginning:

```
last = 0
with open(src_path, "r+") as f:
    for line in f:
        if line == "</END>":
            f.seek(last)
            f.write("whatever you want"
            f.write(line) # rewrite the line
            f.write('\n')
        last = f.tell() # This will give us the end of the last line
```

I did write this code by head so there might be some errors, but you got the idea.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, looks simple and clear. Second approach creates two files causing redundancy, hence I first method seems better ..

Comment: That is true, but in second method there are some risks to erase content. Ofc, in your case, you are modifying the end of the file so it should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't do it with `seek`, since there you have to specify all the offsets yourself - it forces you to explicitly split lines and the like (depending on the OS ...) - all things that tend to be error-prone.

If your grammar prescribes that each -tag is in a separate line, you can use the code you have (it's simple, understandable and presumably fast).

If you need a less strict syntax, then I would build an easy parser with [pyparsing](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/) (assuming that performance is not the main concern).